# TableRow background shape like button

Tags: android, shapes

I want to set a background to a table row to be like this:

[image]

Red hexadecimal numbers in the photo is color code of those area

What should to be background XML file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows, replacing your values in it :

**background_gradient.xml**

1. keep it in `res/drawable`
2. and use it as background for your view like:    android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"

   ```
       <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

           <item><shape>

                   <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#66F2F6FF" android:startColor="#66F2F6FF" />

                   <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#66808080" />
                   <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="11dp" android:bottomRightRadius="11dp" android:topLeftRadius="11dp" android:topRightRadius="11dp" />

               </shape></item>

       </selector>
   ```

Comment: i tested this way , but it's a normally gradient.if you see in the question image,it's really 2 gradient,a gradient from top to center, and another is from center to the bottom